# Error al conectar Visual Studio C# con PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql

tengo un problema al conectar mi Visual Studio con PostgreSQL, mi profesor de programación nos dejo un aplicativo el cual nos ayuda a conectar con la base de datos, pero siempre que compilo el programa me da este error.
Tengo este código para iniciar la conexiona a la base de datos

```
NpgsqlConnection conexion;
        conexion = new NpgsqlConnection("Encoding = UNICODE; Server=" + "localhost" +
                                        ";Port = " + "5432" +
                                        ";User Id=" + "postgres" +
                                        ";Password=" + "luisandres" +
                                        ";Database=" + "prueba" +
                                        ";CommandTimeout=3600;");
        try
        {
            if (conexion.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conexion.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Conexión establecida.");
            }

        }
        catch (NpgsqlException error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error estableciendo conexión, detalle técnico: \n" +
                              error.ErrorCode.ToString() + ": " + error.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

y da este error en un mensaje

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ct51.png]

Si necesitan mas información para poder ayudarme, pedirla en comentarios y se las proporcionare.
Sigo sin poder conectar y tengo que entregar el proyecto el domingo. :(

Comment: Los mensajes de error como texto, porfa. Igual el código que está generando el error... Tantas cosas.... [Empieza por aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  paso por paso.

Comment: Lectura altamente sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Inicio, ejecutar "services.msc" y revisa si los servicios de postgresql están en ejecución.

Comment: @fredyfx eso donde lo ejecuto?

Comment: Presiona `Windows + R` otra opción es presionar tecla Windows y escribir `services`, primera opción que sale.

Comment: Cual seria el archivo que debo verificar?

Comment: En esa lista ha de salir algo referente a `postgresql-XXXX`, mira si el servicio está en ejecución y si no lo está, click derecho, iniciar :) Por otro lado, utiliza el programa DBeaver Community Edition para acceder a esa BD, si logras conectarte con tus credenciales, el problema está en la cadena de conexión de tu app.

Comment: No, no me aparece nada, pero el postgres funciona perfectamente